# Obfuscation not working with proguard

Tags: java, android, proguard, obfuscation, android-proguard

I am using various other libraries. But I have added their proguard configuration from their respository documentation I am not able to obfuscate my code and its inner variable using proguard. Even I am not able to obfuscate package names. I am still able to see logs on my android logcat. My app is running without any crash. I am confused whether minification was applied or not.

This is my app level gradle

```
   defaultConfig {
    resConfigs "en"
    applicationId "com.xxx.xxx"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 25
    versionCode 49
    multiDexEnabled true
    versionName "1.4.2-debug"
}
buildTypes {
    debug {
        minifyEnabled true
        debuggable true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        debuggable true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        signingConfig signingConfigs.config
    }
}
dexOptions {
    javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
}
```

And this is my proguard rules file.

```
-dontpreverify
-repackageclasses ''
-allowaccessmodification
-optimizations !code/simplification/arithmetic
-keepattributes *Annotation*

-keep public class * extends android.app.Activity
-keep public class * extends android.app.Application
-keep public class * extends android.app.Service
-keep public class * extends android.content.BroadcastReceiver
-keep public class * extends android.content.ContentProvider

-keep public class * extends android.view.View {
public <init>(android.content.Context);
public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet);
public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int);
public void set*(...);
}

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet);
}

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int);
}

-keepclassmembers class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
static android.os.Parcelable$Creator CREATOR;
}

-keepclassmembers class **.R$* {
public static <fields>;
}
####################################################################      Fragmenst

-keep public class * extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment
-keep public class * extends android.app.Fragment


####################################################################  Methods

-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
native <methods>;
}
-keepclassmembers class * {
public void *ButtonClicked(android.view.View);
}



####################################################################  Serializables

-keepclassmembers class * implements java.io.Serializable {
static final long serialVersionUID;
private static final java.io.ObjectStreamField[]serialPersistentFields;
!static !transient <fields>;
!private <fields>;
!private <methods>;
private void writeObject(java.io.ObjectOutputStream);
private void readObject(java.io.ObjectInputStream);
java.lang.Object writeReplace();
java.lang.Object readResolve();
}

####################################################################  KEEP ANDROID SUPPORT V7 AND DESIGN

-dontwarn android.support.design.**
-keep class android.support.design.** { *; }
-keep interface android.support.design.** { *; }
-keep public class android.support.design.R$* { *; }

-keep public class android.support.v7.widget.** { *; }
-keep public class android.support.v7.internal.widget.** { *; }
-keep public class android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.** { *; }

-keep public class * extends android.support.v4.view.ActionProvider {
public <init>(android.content.Context);
}

-keep interface android.support.v4.** { *; }
-keep interface android.support.v7.** { *; }
-keep class android.support.** { *; }

####################################################################  REMOVE WARNINGS


-dontwarn android.support.design.internal.**
-dontwarn com.google.android.gms.**
-dontwarn android.support.v4.**


####################################################################  REMOVE LOGGING

-assumenosideeffects class android.util.Log {
public static *** e(...);
public static *** w(...);
public static *** wtf(...);
public static *** d(...);
public static *** v(...);
public static *** i(...);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`I am not able to obfuscate my code and its inner variable using proguard`:

your application seems not obfuscate because your progaurd rules are too broad and they are preventing most of your code from getting minified and obfuscated. for example following line:

```
-keep public class * extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment
-keep public class * extends android.app.Fragment
-keep public class * extends android.app.Activity
-keep public class * extends android.app.Application
-keep public class * extends android.app.Service
-keep public class * extends android.content.BroadcastReceiver
-keep public class * extends android.content.ContentProvider
```

`I am still able to see logs on my android logcat` :

you must remove `debuggable true` from release buildType of your gradle to prevent see logs in logcat.

Comment: I still dont understand why methods inside my class are getting obfuscated but the model and entity classes are not? I haven't written any rule for them.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the line

```
-dontobfuscate
```

in my proguard file which was blocking the obfuscation